# Is there any operator method of mutable collections that can write the result back to the mutable operator invoker or argument?

Tags: scala, collections, operators

`::`, `:::` operator methods of `List` return a new `List`.
`+` operator method of `Set` or `Map` returns a new `Set` or `Map`, and so on.
Do all operator methods of collections return a new collection?
Is there any operator method of mutable collections out of the ordinary that can write the result back to the mutable operator invoker or argument?
So that I don't need to reassign the result to the mutable invoker or argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+=` should work

The example from internet

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

val fruits = ArrayBuffer[String]()
fruits += "Apple"
fruits += "Banana"
fruits += "Orange"

val x = Map("AL" -> "Alabama")
x += ("AK" -> "Alaska")
```

Comment: But i wonder is there any way to add an array without getting a new object, which would be equivalent to ++

Comment: you should change `var` to `val` as `fruits` stays the same.

Comment: @pme, yes, i did

Comment: @pme Because the ArrayBuffer and Map in the listing above are mutable, there is no need to reassign them, which is why they can be vals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do all operator methods of collections return a new collection?

In a functional world yes, as everything is  **immutable**.

As *Scala* also supports *imperativ* style there are operators on *mutable* collections.
See the examples in *Dimitry's* answer.